# Ansible multiple regexp when state

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to replace name in file based on the artifacts that ansible has collected.
It's there some simple way to achieve this task with **ONE** `lineinfile`

Something like this,

```
lineinfile:
    path: '/somefile.conf'
    regexp: '{{ item.regexp }}'
    line: '{{ item.line }}'
  with_items:
    - { regexp: '^DB_TYPE=', line: "DB_TYPE=mysql" } when: mysql.stat.exists
    - { regexp: '^DB_TYPE=', line: "DB_TYPE=oracle" } when: oracle.stat.exists
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `if ... else ... if`

```
  lineinfile:
    path: '/somefile.conf'
    regexp: '^DB_TYPE='
    line: "{{ 'DB_TYPE=mysql' if mysql.stat.exists else 'DB_TYPE=oracle' if oracle.stat.exists }}"
```

Comment: How can I define a variable in this loop. For example I want to put the IP address but I can't exit the loop. here is example


```
 lineinfile:
    path: '/somefile.conf'
    regexp: '^IP_ADDR='
    line: "{{ 'IP_ADDR=127.0.0.1' if mysql.stat.exists else 'DB_TYPE={{ansible_all_ipv4_addresses}}' if oracle.stat.exists }}"
```

Comment: If you want to consider only the first IP on the list of IP addresses, the `line` would be `line: "{{ 'IP_ADDR=127.0.0.1' if mysql.stat.exists else IP_ADDR=' ~ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0] if oracle.stat.exists }}"`

Comment: Great answer @franklinsijo .
How can achive the same but with mixed variable + text. Something like this:

 lineinfile: path: '/somefile.conf' regexp: '^URL=' line: "{{ 'URL=127.0.0.1' if mysql.stat.exists else 'URL=http://{{ansible_all_ipv4_addresses}}/test' if oracle.stat.exists }}"

Comment: It is similar concatenation as above, `'URL=http://' ~ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0] ~ '/test'`

Answer (score 0):

I believe `when` conditions are tied to a task, and thus you cannot have different conditions for different loops in the same task (happy to be corrected here).

This leaves you a couple options:

1. Split this into multiple `lineinfile` tasks, which it sounds like you want to avoid.
2. Make use of [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) module. Not necessarily better, but cool to be aware of.

An example of the second option:

```
- name: set database type for mysql deployment
  set_fact:
    _db_type: mysql
  when: mysql.stat.exists

- name: set database type for oracle deployment
  set_fact:
    _db_type: oracle
  when: oracle.stat.exists

- name: something something
  lineinfile:
    path: '/somefile.conf'
    regexp: '^DB_TYPE='
    line: "DB_TYPE={{ _db_type }}"
```

I find this helpful if there are multiple tasks where you'll need to refer to either mysql or oracle (as an example).